# How to update documents in mongdb using bulk operation?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to access a single table inside of a single function using python and tornado.

From the suggestions for my previous question am trying to use `Bulk` operation available in `mongodb` to do so. My attempt to insert was successful but during update am getting error.

My code is

```
bulk = db.Test.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
print("1")
bulk.insert({"test":"we"})
# bulk.find({"test": "we"})
bulk.update({"test": "we"},{'$set':{"test": "false"}},{'$unset':{"Cid"}})
t = bulk.execute()
print(t)
```

Is something wrong in the query?

And when trying to print the answer to the `find` operation am getting

```
<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x02ED2630>
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do this bulk operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `.find()` what you want to `.update()`.

```
bulk.find({"test": "we"}).update({'$set': {"test": "false"}, '$unset': {"Cid", ""}})
```

Also you to find documents in your collection simply use the [`.find`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)  method which returns a `Cursor` object. You will then need to iterate over the cursor or use `list` to return the documents. That being said if know that your query will return only one document then what you need is the [`.find_one()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method.

In your printing the result of [`bulk.find`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html?highlight=bulk#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder.find) doesn't make any sense because you are inserting the document, updating using the same instance of  [`BulkOperationBuilder`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html?highlight=bulk#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder) which means that all your operations will be sent to the server after [`.execute()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html?highlight=bulk#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder.execute)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Motor, you need to "yield" the Future returned by bulk.execute in order to await its completion and get a result:

```
@gen.coroutine
def f():
    bulk = db.Test.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    print("1")
    bulk.insert({"test":"we"})
    # bulk.find({"test": "we"})
    bulk.update({"test": "we"},{'$set':{"test": "false"}},{'$unset':{"Cid"}})
    t = yield bulk.execute()
    print(t)
```

Motor is asynchronous; in order to wait for any Motor method that talks to the database server to complete you must either pass a callback to the method, or yield the Future the method returns.

For more information consult the tutorial:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations